# -a option in `cp` command -- what does it do?

Tags: linux, unix, cp, manpage

What does the `-a` option do in the `cp` command?

I thought that the `-a` does not preserve the structure of directories.  But, I have never found a case where the structure of directories has been destroyed by the `-a` option.

is there such a case where the structure of directories has been destroyed by the `-a` option?  Thanks.

Comment: What does the [tag:man] tag mean in this context?

Comment: What has become of the fine art of reading the fine manual page, especially when you want to know what an option does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-a means 3 things:

1. preserve timestamps, permissions, group, user (if you're running as root).
2. preserves symbolic links (no dereference)
3. recursive copy

read the man page, it has all info there

Answer (score 0):

```
       -a, --archive
          same as -dR --preserve=all
```

To my understanding, it should recursively copy the directories while keeping all the attributes. In which case, it shouldn't be destroying the structure at all.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html